# Det of Jacobian becomes 0 when computing Joint density of $V_1=X^2+Y^2$ and $V_2=X^2−Y^2$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable, jacobian

I am trying to solve the following.

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables distributed as Uniform$([−1, 1])$. Give the joint density of $U,V$, where $U=X^2+Y^2$ and $V =X^2 - Y^2$.

I am using change of variables method to solve this.

g<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>(U,V) -> (U + V / 2)<sup>1/2</sup> = x

g<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup>(U,V) -> (U - V / 2)<sup>1/2</sup> = y

Let L = g<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>(U,V) and K = g<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup>(U,V)

When I compute Det of Jacobian matrix, it becomes zero.

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial L}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial K}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial K}{\partial v}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sqrt{U + V}} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sqrt{U - V}} \\
\frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sqrt{U + V}} & \frac{\sqrt 2}{4\sqrt{U - V}}
\end{pmatrix}= 0
$$

Need help on what I making mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Check again. It is not $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have added my jacobian, can you let me know the mistake I am making. Thanks in advance

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{(u-v)/2}$ with respect to $v$ should have another minus sign from the chain rule.

Comment: Your differentiation is not correct. Also, $X$ and $Y$ take values in $[-1,1]$. You have assumed that they are positive.  To differentiate $y$ w.r.tt $v$ you have to apply chain rule and you will get  factor of $(-1)$.

Comment: thanks @KaviRamaMurthy , I found the issue incorrect differentiation , but I am not able to understand the 2nd part of the comment. "Also,  and  take values in [−1,1]. You have assumed that they are positive" . Can you explain further on this. Thanks

Comment: $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac {U+V} 2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U = X^2 + Y^2, V = X^2 - Y^2$

$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}}, y = \pm\sqrt{\frac{u-v}{2}}$

$\det\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\pm\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2\sqrt{u + v}} & \pm\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2\sqrt{u + v}} \\
\pm\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2\sqrt{u - v}} & \mp\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2\sqrt{u - v}}
\end{pmatrix}= \pm\frac{1}{4\sqrt{u^2 - v^2}}$

So, $|J| = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{u^2 - v^2}}$

Comment: The formulas for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $U$ and $V$ is not correct since $X,Y$ are not positive r.v.'s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes missed that $x,y \in [-1,1]$